# Java - Futures not Cancelling

Tags: java, future, executorservice, cancellation, futuretask

I have had a problem with my futures returned from my ExecutorService not cancelling properly for some time. I have written an MCVE which I believe captures the root of my problems.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainTest extends Application {

private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
private int lowResolution = 20;
private List<Future<Object>> lowResFutureList = 
        Collections.synchronizedList(new  ArrayList<Future<Object>>());
private List<Future<Object>> highResFutureList = 
        Collections.synchronizedList(new  ArrayList<Future<Object>>());

private Slider slider = new Slider();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                updateLowResImage();
            }
        });
        slider.showTickLabelsProperty().set(true);
        slider.showTickMarksProperty().set(true);
        slider.setMax(60);

        Scene scene = new Scene(slider);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void updateLowResImage() {
        System.out.println("HighResFutures: " + highResFutureList.size() + "\n"
                + "LowResFutures: " + lowResFutureList.size());
        for(Future<Object> future : lowResFutureList) {
            if(future != null) {
                System.out.println("Attempting low res cancel: " + future.cancel(false));   
            }
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Future<Object> future = threadPool.submit(new ImageTask(lowResolution, lowResolution));
                lowResFutureList.add(future);
                try {
                    future.get();
                    System.out.println("Low res Future completed.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Low resolution Future cancelled.");
                } finally {
                    lowResFutureList.remove(future);
                }
            }
        }).start();

        int resolution = (int) slider.getValue();
        if(resolution > lowResolution) {
            updateHighResImage(resolution);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void updateHighResImage(int resolution) {
        for(Future<Object> future : highResFutureList) {
            if(future != null) {
                System.out.println("Attempting high res cancel: " + future.cancel(true));   
            }
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            Future<Object> future = threadPool.submit(new ImageTask(resolution, resolution));
                highResFutureList.add(future);
                try {
                    future.get();
                    System.out.println("High res Future completed.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("High resolution Future cancelled.");
                } finally {
                    highResFutureList.remove(future);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private class ImageTask implements Callable<Object> {

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        private ImageTask(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    if(Thread.interrupted()) {
                        System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                        return null;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.print("Cancelled! ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Continued!");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe some explaining is necessary. So the code brings up a `Slider` with a range from 0 to 60. Every time the slider changes its value it should create a `Task` that counts 20^2 milliseconds. When this is done it starts another thread which counts `slider.getValue()`^2 milliseconods if `slider.getValue()` is greater than 20. These `Task`s are submitted to an `ExecutorService`.

Now if the `Slider` changes its value while different `Task`s are already counting milliseconds these `Task`s should be cancelled and the new ones should start counting instead.

As you can see there are some print statements in the code. If I move the `Slider` vigorously close to 50 I expect to see something like the quote below as I let go of the `Slider`.

> HighResFutures: 1
>   LowResFutures: 1
>   Attempting low res cancel: false
>   Attempting high res cancel: true
>   Interrupted!
>   Low resolution Future cancelled.
>   High resolution Future cancelled.
>   Continued!
>   Low res Future completed.
>   Continued!
>   High res Future completed.

But what I see is this:

> HighResFutures: 1
>   LowResFutures: 1
>   Attempting low res cancel: true
>   Attempting high res cancel: true
>   Low resolution Future cancelled.
>   High resolution Future cancelled.
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Low res Future completed.
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   Continued!
>   High res Future completed.

So the first thing to note is that the cancellation of the low resolution `Future`s is successful even though it should not be able to cancel ongoing `Task`s (does this mean it hasn't had time to start?). Secondly I never get "Interrupted!" printed. And lastly "Continued!" is printed several times before completion of the final `Task` which makes me believe that almost none of the `Task`s are cancelled properly. What is your take on this? I am very new to `ExecutorService` and have no idea what is going on. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think highResFutureList.add(future);  call just after the Thread start, so if you have say 5  threads that haven't start it will not help to call future.cancel(true) because of it not in the list yet, you need to move  highResFutureList.add(future); out of the thread and do just the   future.get(); in the thread

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht this is probably true. Is there a way to make this an atomic operation (so that no process is allowed between these operations). Do you have any comments concerning the two other peculiarities?